# Get several unique fields values in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(...)
    b = models.CharField(...)
```

And some substring `"substring"`
To get all unique values from fields `a` and `b` which contains those substring I can do that:

```
a_values = MyModel.objects.filter(a__icontains=substring).values_list("a", flat=True).distinct()
b_values = MyModel.objects.filter(b__icontains=substring).values_list("b", flat=True).distinct()  

unique_values = list(set([*a_values, *b_values]))
```

Is it possible to rewrite it with one database request?

**PS to clarify**
from objects:

```
MyModel(a="x", b="y")
MyModel(a="xx", b="xxx")
MyModel(a="z", b="xxxx")
```

by substring `"x"` I expect to get:

```
unique_values = ["x", "xx", "xxx", "xxxx"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can here make a union of two queries that are never evaluated individually, like:

```
qa = MyModel.objects.filter(a__icontains=query).values_list('a', flat=True)
qb = MyModel.objects.filter(b__icontains=query).values_list('b', flat=True)
result = list(qa.union(qb))
```

Since `qa` and `qb` are *lazy* querysets, we never evaluate these. The query that will be performed is:

```
(
    SELECT mymodel.a
    FROM mymodel
    WHERE mymodel.a LIKE %query%
)
UNION
(
    SELECT mymodel.b
    FROM mymodel
    WHERE mymodel.b
    LIKE %query%
)
```

The union furthermore will only select *distinct* values. Even if a value occurs both in `a` and in `b`, it will only be retrieved *once*.

For example:

```
>>> MyModel(a="x", b="y").save()
>>> MyModel(a="xx", b="xxx").save()
>>> MyModel(a="z", b="xxxx").save()
>>> query = 'x'
>>> qa = MyModel.objects.filter(a__icontains=query).values_list('a', flat=True)
>>> qb = MyModel.objects.filter(b__icontains=query).values_list('b', flat=True)
>>> list(qa.union(qb))
['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx']
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use it!

Answer (score 0):

why not get both of them in the values and then flatten the list ?

```
unique_values = MyModel.objects.filter(
    Q(a__icontains=substring) | Q(b__icontains=substring)
).values_list("a", "b").distinct()
unique_values = sum(unqiue_values, [])
```

if sum doesnt work here, then you can probably use flatten from itertools. Sum won't probably work because we getting a list of tuples instead of list of lists. Sorry i couldn't test this right now.

Comment: because in that query i'll get values from a or b not only contains my substring (for.ex. `MyModel(a="something", b="something substring something")`. In final list `unique_values` i expect to see `"something substring something"` string, not `"something"`)

Comment: I've extend my question by example

Comment: @ruhaib: but the above will retrieve values for b that do not match substring (and the same for a), since if `a__icontains=substring` matches, then `'b'` will be returned for that value. Furthermore the `.distinct()` will only check for uniqness of the combined values. So `('x', 'y')` will be seen as different than `('y', 'x')` whereas there is no need to retrieve this an extra time.

Comment: @Williem you are right, the clarification cleared things for me but i couldn't update the answer in time.